# MVC5, insert or update a list of data with just one submit

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm building a CBT content manager web apps.

I'm going to handle a hundred of question lists and four answers per a question.

Below is the models by the way.

```
public partial class CbtItem : AldesiMongoBase<CbtItem>
{
        [Browsable(false)]
        public ObjectId id { get; set; }
        public string CbtClass { get; set; }
        public string Inning { get; set; }
        public string Sort { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string QuestionImage { get; set; }
        public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

And the Answer class is...

```
public partial class Answer
    {
        [BsonIgnore]
        public ObjectId ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Sort { get; set; }
        public string AnswerText { get; set; }
        public string AnswerImage { get; set; }
        public bool IsAnswer { get; set; }
    }
```

And the view using these models.

```
@model IEnumerable<Aldesi.Model.CbtItem>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "input data";
}
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $('#ajaxCall').click(function (e) {

            });
        });

    </script>

    <div id="subHeader">
        <h2>@Html.Raw(string.Format("{0} {1} ", Request.Params["cbtclass"], Request.Params["inning"]))</h2>
        <div id="ajaxCall" class="createTestButton aldesi-button">
            <span>
                Submit
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sort)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subject)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Question)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QuestionImage)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Answers)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="cbtItems">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sort)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Subject)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Question)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.QuestionImage)
                </td>

                <td class="ansItems">
                    @if (item.Answers != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var ansItems in item.Answers)
                        {
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ansItems.Sort)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => ansItems.AnswerText)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => ansItems.AnswerImage) <br />
                        }
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

}
```

This view is for both edit and list view purpose.

I can edit items or create new through updating them.

What I want to do is to insert or update the data list with just one submit.

But MVC seems to communicate with server through form submit so, I think I need a workaround for this.

The view is going to draw 100 fields and 800 answer fields and those fields are going to have the same id and name, which means the form-submit will consume just one list out of 100.

Any ideas? is Ajax the best candidate for this?

Comment: You need to construct you questions and answers using a `for` loop rather than a `foreach` loop so that the controls are correctly named with indexers, or you can create a custom `EditorTemplate`. The the list will be bound correctly on post back

Comment: @StephenMuecke Out of curiosity is this an MVC5 thing, or is this because it's a nested collection? I seem to remember doing something similar with a foreach loop (albeit with no nesting) and at least MVC4 named the controls correctly.

Comment: No difference between MVC 4 and 5 with respect to this. You can only use a `foreach` loop if you have custom `Editortemplates` e.g. `CbtItem.cshtml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a `foreach` loop... use a `for` loop and iterate through the indexes of your collection / list...

Also you'll need to use a `List<T>` for your Model... `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have an indexer, so you wont be able to use it.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr class="cbtItems">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Sort)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].Subject)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].Question)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].QuestionImage)
        </td>

        <td class="ansItems">
            @if (Model[i].Answers != null)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Answers.Count(); j++)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Answers[j].Sort)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].Answers[j].AnswerText)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].Answers[j].AnswerImage) <br />
                }
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: I changed IEnumerable<T> to List<T> in @Using code. But in the for loop, Model is considered as IEnumerable. How can I handle this?

Answer (score -1):

For other people having issues with binding collections,

You could check out the BeginCollectionItem helper. It handles this for you and works really well with complex viewModels with multiple collections, handles validation and keeps your views clean. As it's still using the default model binder, it will support normal and ajax posts.

[Git](https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem)

[Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/)

You can find plenty of documentation for it. It does work in MVC5 with razor (not shown in old examples)
example - http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/